# Getting error by passing a large string in js function via php

Tags: javascript, php

```
          while($var=$result->fetch_assoc())
           {
            $page = $var['page'];
            // echo $page;
            
            $desc=$var['description'];
            // echo $desc;
            
            echo "<script>showbook(\"$page\",\"$desc\")</script>";
        }
```

Problem is iam having 700 characters of string in column 'description' of text data type in MySQL table which is now stored in $desc variable.
I tried to inspect the code and found that the echo script statement is not able to execute.but for small strings it is able to echo the script tag. How do I modify my code to make it work for larger strings passed as an argument to js function? Iam looking for a solid method which works even the text contains single or double qoutes.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible that the string `$desc` contains special characters such as `"`?

Comment: @Professor No it has '.' though

Comment: What exactly does "the echo script statement is not able to execute" mean? Are you getting any error messages? Have you enabled error messages?

Comment: iam getting the following error:bookmark.php:42 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token